# Add Margin on Smooth Scroll

Tags: jquery, offset, smooth-scrolling

I am adding smoothscrolling to my one-page freelance site.
Whenever it scrolls to the page it shows 60px from the top of the section bc of the fix-top nav as you scroll looking like this when it scrolls down

[image: this]

When I'd like it to push 60px down and scroll down to look like this instead.

[image]

I pulled scroll code from w3 bc their solution seems the simplest.  Just starting to use jquery more so any help would be greatly appreciate.
Code used below:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {

      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1100, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      } // End if
    });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making the offset based on the .navbar height instead of hard-coding the height in, so if the content changes, or you reuse the code you don't have to continue to change it.  You could also improve upon the script in how it handles the hashes, and allow any URL starting with a hash to have the smooth scroll:

```
$( function() {
    $( 'a[href^="#"]' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {

        if ( this.hash !== '' ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;
            var nav = $( '.navbar' ).outerHeight();

            $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                scrollTop: $( hash ).offset().top - nav
            }, 1100, function() {
                window.location.hash = hash;
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually about to fix this myself by add  - 60 after  top$(hash).offset().top

Changed section if anyone else ever has this issue:

```
('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 60
}, 1100, function(){
```